# Why am I getting Type error: `[]' expected, found `[21,3,4,5,6,7,8]' (a list) ("x" must hold one character) with maplist/3 prolog?

Tags: prolog, maplist

I am new to Prolog. I want a predicate that takes a list, process it with maplist/3 creating a corresponding list with zeros in place of numbers less than mean and 1 for number above the mean. I then want a second predicate to sum the 1's to find out how many numbers are above the  mean. This second predicate then returns this number which corresponds to total numbers above the mean.

I know the code below works fine:

```
numAtOrAboveMean(Mean, Num, Val) :- Num > Mean -> Val  is 1; Val is 0.
maplist(numAtOrAboveMean(Mean), [], List), sumlist(List, Below).
```

When I modified it to this, I get a type erros that expected [] but found a list. The comments correspond to how I think the predicate behavior is.

```
nGMean(Mean, Num, Val) :- Num > Mean -> Val  is 1; Val is 0.%sorts list
nGMean([], _ , []). %takes a list, a constant, relates to a list
nGMean(L, Mean, List) : - maplist(nGMean(Mean), L, List). %maplist call sort
```

Then to sum I will use a second predicate. Something like this:

```
sumtotal(L,V) :- mean(L, M), M2 is M, nGMean(L, M2, List), sum(List, V).
```

Which is not working probably mostly because nGMean is throwing an error. nGMean full error is shown below:

[image: nGmean predicate Error]

So my question is, why am I getting that type error on the nGMean predicate?

Edit -As requested in comments below is the entire thing. As I explained that is the only part because I am testing it separately.
Thank you for answers. Next time I will post complete code.Or make clear that I just want to trouble shoot one predicate.

[Maplist for numAtOrAboveMean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Rc1.png)

[Full Pic of code on Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DquJS.png)

Comment: *ERROR: c/users/pcbcj/downloads/file3.pl:6:* Check line 6 in your `file3.pl` file. That's the first error you need to fix. The message gave you the line number. What Prolog interpreter are you using?

Comment: You need to show at least the first 6 lines from your `file3.pl`.

Comment: Hello, Line six corresponds to  the last line on predicate.                                                                                                              
         nGMean(L, Mean, List) : - maplist(nGMean(Mean), L, List). %maplist 
        call sort

Comment: I am using Hessischer Bildungsserver with SWI prolog

Comment: Could you show then the entire first 6 lines of your file all at once instead of broken up into pieces to see what your interpreter sees?

Comment: I was testing that predicate separately, so it is the only thing on the file - the predicate and blank lines are it. I will post a pic tomorrow (not home)

Comment: No pic, please. Show the first 6 lines in the text of your question. You can just copy/paste it in and indent it to show up as code.

Comment: `nGMean` is probably not the error but the first non-incorrect bit immediately following. Your line starting with `maplist` look funny as it has only a comma on the top level. I don't think this is valid syntax. You might get better help if you just post all the code.

Comment: I will add a picture to main post, that is all the code. I am testing only that separately because was giving me a hard time.

Comment: @PaulaCavalcanti - You define `numAtOrAboveMean` as `numAtOrAboveMean/3` but then you call it with one parameter. You also do that with `nGMean`. Why are you doing that?

Comment: @Enigmativity - numAtOrAboveMean has three parameters - input list, input mean, return list - no?

Comment: @PaulaCavalcanti - But you try to call it with one parameter - `numAtOrAboveMean(Mean)`.

Comment: @Enigmativity - are you referring to: maplist(numAtOrAboveMean(Mean), [], List)? If so, Mean here is the goal in maplist to satisfy maplist(:Goal, ?List1, ?List2) -  still passing all three. No?

Comment: @PaulaCavalcanti - Yes, but the goal is `numAtOrAboveMean(Mean)` - which only has one parameter.

Comment: @Enigmativity - No, it takes three parameters and it works fine on swi prolog. Could you clarify what you mean? maplist(numAtOrAboveMean(Mean), [], List)  Goal= mean, List 1=[], List return.

Comment: ?- maplist(numAtOrAboveMean(3), [1,2,3,4,5], List).
List = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]., I added a picture on the main post

Answer (score 3):

You should post complete code that can just be copied and run. In what you have posted, `mean/2` and `sum/2` are not defined.

(Addition:) the reason for the error seems to be that you are comparing a value and a list (`2<[2,3|...]`). The reason this happens is because your first clause for `nGMean/3` has `Mean` as first parameter, whereas the other clauses has the list, i.e. the list becomes `Mean` which is used in the comparison (`Num > Mean`). I'm not sure how `>` becomes `<`.

Also, calling `maplist/3` on an empty list does not make sense.

A recursive predicate should have two clauses. A recursive clause that (typically) does something with the head of the list and then calls recursively on the tail, and a base case (empty list).

```
nGMean([Num|Nums],Mean,[Val|List]) :-
  ( Num > Mean ->
    Val = 1
  ; Val = 0 ),
  nGMean(Nums,Mean,List).
nGMean([],_,[]).
```

With this definition I get the same output as your first two lines above, so I believe this is what you wanted.

(Earlier addition: you only need to use `is` when the right-hand side contains mathematical calculations. To just set a value, `=` is fine.)

Comment: Hello, the reason it seems I am comparing a list with a number is because that part is being called via maplist. So, as far as I know you can do that. Also, my bad on not posting the entire code but I really wanted to trouble shoot only nGMean.

Comment: Just to clarify: I am using maplist to compare each element of the list with the mean.  Which is a legit prolog operation, for more:                                                                                                                    http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3